# How to remove active_id from the URL in Odoo 13?

Tags: odoo, odoo-13

I am deleting a record from a wizard action and return the same parent action( not wizard action) and showing the tree view properly.
But issue is in the latest URL in address bar(After deleting a record), a new parameter called `active_id` appeared with value of deleted record id.

URL before deleting the record

```
 http://localhost:8069/web?debug=assets#id=160451&action=285&model=my.custom.model&view_type=form&cids=1&menu_id=125
```

URL after deleting the record

```
 http://localhost:8069/web?debug=assets#active_id=897&model=my.custom.model&view_type=list&cids=&menu_id=125
```

Here u can see `active_id=897` coming from somewhere, I think it is an ID of the wizard.
And an issue arise when I open a record and perform a button action getting the following error,

```
 Record does not exist or has been deleted.
 (Record: absent.info(898,), User: 398)
```

End of the button action of the wizard I tried to return in following ways, but nothing succeeded.

```
        #Removed the active_id and active_ids from the context.
        context = self.env.context.copy()
        context.pop('active_id',None)
        context.pop('active_ids',None)
        keys_to_remove = ['active_id','active_ids']
        action_id  = self.env.ref('my_custom_action')
        action_data = {'type': 'ir.actions.client', 'tag': 'reload'}
        result = {'type': 'ir.actions.act_window_close'}  # Optional: close the current window
        return result, action_id
```

```
        return {
            'type': 'ir.actions.client',
            'tag': 'reload',
        }


        return {
            'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
            'res_model': 'my.custom.model',
            'view_mode': 'tree,form',
            'res_id': None,
            # 'views': [(False, 'form')],
            # 'target': 'new',
        }
        
        return action_id
        


        return {
            'name': 'Absent Info',
            'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
            'view_mode': 'tree,form',
            'res_model': 'absent.info',
            # 'view_id':self.env.ref('fingent_hr_holidays.view_absent_info_tree').id,
            'context': context,
            # 'context': self._context,
            'target': 'main',
        }
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by redirecting to a URL of the action.
Here is the code.

```
    action_id  = self.env.ref('my_module.my_custom_action')
    url = self.env['ir.config_parameter'].sudo().get_param('web.base.url')+'/web#action='+str(action_id.id)+'&model=custom.model&view_type=list'
    return {
        'type': 'ir.actions.act_url',
        'url': url,
        'target': 'self',  # Open in the same window
    }
```